# Eclipse .cproject file no longer indents with tabs, but now with spaces

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm not sure if or how I did this, but my Eclipse .cproject file has been changed to be indented with spaces.

2nd strange thing is that the file is also double spaced, with the "blank" line containing first spaces and then tabs (the spaces and tabs match what goes at the beginning of the next line).

No big deal really only space changes, **but** a pain for version control, especially if someone else's Eclipse is converting it back.

Comment: I've just noticed the issue on 2020-06; do you know what version of Eclipse you were using and if you'd recently updated it? (I know; it was a long time ago....)

Comment: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) BLD ID: 20190917-1200

Comment: Thanks. I asked the same question on the Eclipse CDT forum and some idiot came out with the same stuff as in the answers below! Presumably you never resolved it? I've also raised it as a bug at the Eclipse bugzilla.

Comment: @cosimo193 What's the bug number?

Comment: 565628: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=565628

Comment: did any one found a solution to this problem? any updates

Answer (score 0):

Your code formatting style may have been changed. You may need to select a different formatting style or edit the current one. It sounds like your indentation style is set to mixed and is configured to indent empty lines.

In Eclipse 2019-06, your formatting style can be modified globally in

> Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> Formatting

or if you have project specific settings enabled, in

> Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Formatter

Other versions of Eclipse should have similar settings

Comment: to be clear, I'm NOT talking about the code itself (java, c/c++, cs)... but rather the xml project file.  i did look at the formatting settings for xml, but it is set to use tabs already.

Comment: I don't think the C/C++ formatting applies to the .cproject file in this case.

Answer (score -2):

The contents of the `.cproject` file are an implementation detail, and liable to change from one Eclipse version to the next.

They're not meant to be checked into version control, unless you're in an environment where everyone is using the exact same version of Eclipse, in which case you just need to update it in version control once, and "someone else's Eclipse converting it back" should never happen.

Comment: `.cproject` and everything in the project folder is intended to be checked into version control. `.cproject` contains project specific C/C++ Eclipse settings/configuration that should be the same for all developers (who hopefully don't use an outdated Eclipse, even if it probably doesn't matter here).

Comment: @howlger Whether or not it makes sense to commit `.cproject` will depend on the circumstances. For example, a project may generate `.cproject` from CMake, in which case it can be considered a build artifact.

Comment: Of course, if `.cproject` can be generated (e.g. via CMake), it does not necessarily have to be versioned. But that wasn't the point.

Comment: even same version cdt in 2 os may generated diferent .cproject with tab or space
It use somehow  not be the case I had no issue checking in project and using them in  Windows/Mac/Linux
But since neon and some projec not all t just keep changing  and I can't find why :(

Comment: @HighCommander4 I suggest you look at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=565628. It is, in fact, an issue with Eclipse CDT (and other bits of Eclipse) and the XML indentation stuff in Java which, before Java 11, didn't work properly.